# Extremely slow computer

Tags: performance, operating-systems

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit. It takes forever to boot up my computer and it is full of lag. It takes about a whole minute in the loading windows 7 screen, and after logging in (entering password), it takes about another 30 seconds to load up my desktop. I also have a black screen for 10 seconds. I'm completely going crazy with such lag. It lags a bit during use as well. Solution? (Note: It worked really fast when I had Windows 8.1 but I do not like the UI on it).

Processor: Intel Core i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10 GHz
RAM: 2 GB
System Type: 64 bit.

If you need any other details, please request them in the Comments section.

Comment: Does this happen when you configured Windows to boot into a minimal configuration?  We really need more information.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not sure about all that. Can you guide me on how to check that? I will tell all information you need.

Comment: I don't remember doing such a thing though, but I'll update my post with my specs

Comment: There are tons of tutorials that explain how to configure Windows in such a state that only the bare minimum applications it normally will start upon user login will be started.

Comment: How do I do that @Ramhound

Comment: If you researched how to do what I am asking you would find dozens of tutorials on how to do it.

Comment: capture a boot trace and share it: http://pastebin.com/CYGqRZXE

Answer (score 2):

Well, without more information I think that the problem could be really simple: The RAM. 2GB of ram are really little for a Windows 7 ultimate especially for a 64bit version. Even Windows says,that 2GB are the minimal requirements to run windows 7 ultimate.

Also Windows 8 needs [less RAM than Windows 7](http://www.askvg.com/comparison-between-windows-7-and-windows-8-memory-management-system/) so that would be an explanation why Windows 8 ran better.

I would highly recommend to upgrade your RAM. For the interim you could trim your startup by following [this tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/bump-performance-in-windows-7-by-trimming-startup-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions (as others have said, without more information a real diagnosis is hard)

- Needs more RAM (or an OS that requires less) as stated by others.
- Ensure that you don't have lots of unnecessary processes and programs starting at boot time - even the ones just running in the background that you might not know of.
- Ensure you don't have a malware infection of any kind (I'd recommend running an AV scan like MSE as well as an active protection scanner like MalwareBytes).